# How to get distinct keys of a nested object in an elasticsearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to look across an index for a unique list of keys in a nested object.

So in the example below, I want the output

```
["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "sigma", "theta" ]
```

Much of the google search results were around unique values instead of the keys.

Example docs:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "fooNested": {
        "alpha": 1,
        "beta": 4,
        "gamma": 2,
     }
},
{
    "foo": "HelloWorld",
    "fooNested": {
        "sigma": 9,
        "theta": 1
     }
}
```

Is this possible using the rest api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) api to get all properties in index and parse it client side to list properties under nested object or you can store fields as values and query it.

```
example.
"fooNested": {
        "sigma": 9,
        "theta": 1,
        "keys":["sigma","theta"]
     }
```

Comment: Using your tip, I went with GET http://localhost:9200/indexTest/_mapping/field/fooNested*